# issue regarding dropdown menu

Tags: jquery

my problem is coming with the dropdown. m using jquery there and if i continuously move the mouser over the menu all menu start coming slideIn and Out.  i just want that only the current menu should slide. and other effect should die. plz help me finding the solution from last 1 week. thanks in advance :)

this is my code snippet of jquery

```
$('.navigation li').bind({
          mouseenter: function() {

            $('.hov', this).slideUp('fast');  
            $('.hov', this).slideDown();
          },
          mouseleave: function() {
              $('.hov', this).slideUp();

          }
});
```

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 0):

[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) - Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.