# Issue regarding JQuery Sliding SubMenu and repeated animations

Tags: jquery

That link got the same problem as the one I'm having:
[issue regarding dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906223/issue-regarding-dropdown-menu)

This is my code

```
$("document").ready(function() {
   menuFunc (); 
});
function menuFunc (){
    $('#nav').on('mouseenter mouseleave','li',function (){
            $(this)
                .removeClass('noJS')
                .children('ul')
                    .slideToggle(200);
            });
    };
```

How and where to use the .stop() to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
function menuFunc (){
$('#nav').on('mouseenter mouseleave','li',function (){
        $(this)
            .removeClass('noJS')
            .children('ul').stop()
                .slideToggle(200);
        });
};
```